# CSS - Looking to create a box with some text inside. Example inside

Tags: html, css

Here is an example [image: example.]

Now, this is my first attempt:

```
.generated_text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54%;
    left: 36%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    width:700px;
    height:400px;
}
```

NOTE: `generated_text` is a div that outputs text generated from a flask api.

When I ran this, it ends up looking like this:

[image]

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to css so any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I made some updates but still running into some issues:

```
.generated_text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    font-family:'Gudea' !important;
    text-align: left;
    color:#000 !important;
    background:#fff !important;
    border: 30px !important;
    border-color: #4b4b4b !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54%;
    left: 38.5%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    width:560px;
    height:170px;
}
```

Which yields:

[image]

Any ideas for why the border color isnt showing up?

Comment: Is there any other div with a similar name as `generated_text` ?

Comment: your code is incomplete add u r complete code

Comment: @AbhishekPakhare; No there isn't.

Comment: @AmareshSM The HTML and the CSS?

Comment: Are you using any `css` framework ?

Comment: @AbhishekPakhare, yes i am

Comment: Which `css` framework?

Answer (score 0):

try **!important** when you received data from api like this :

```
.generated_text {
   color:#000 !important;
   background:#fff !important;
   width:100%;
   text-align: center;
   clear:both;
   display:block;
   font-size:25px;
   border:1.5px solid #4b4b4b !important;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) !important;
}
```

Comment: I edit it now ,in the last line(border and box-shadow)